# What is this regex error when trying to display Django User profile?

Tags: python, regex, django, url, django-class-based-views

I'm trying to use regex to capture a user's username, and use a CBV to return a JSON response showing the correct User's info, but I am getting an error I don't understand.

First off, here is the error I am getting:

url(r'^userprofile/(?P[\w.@+-]+)', UserProfile.as_view()),
NameError: name 'UserProfile' is not defined

I have other URL captures that are working just fine, and they are all CBV just like this one, with the same format.

Here is the URL capture code:

`url(r'^userprofile/(?P<username>[\w.@+-]+)', UserProfile.as_view())`

Here is the CBV:

```
class UserProfile(APIView):
    def get(self, request, username):
        obj = User.objects.get(username=username)
        serializer = UserSerializer(obj, many=True)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)
```

Here is the UserSerializer:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('__all__')
```

And here is the User Model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    birthdate = models.DateField(null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(
        max_length=1,
        choices=(('M', 'Male'), ('F', 'Female'), ('O', 'Other'), ('U', 
        'Unspecified')),
        default='Unspecified'
    )
    renewal = models.DateField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

This is probably simple, but I don't know why this error is being thrown.  Please advise.  Thanks you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't a regex error. The message says exactly what it is: it's a NameError, because UserProfile is not defined. You need to import it in the urls.py where you use it.

Comment: Hmmm, thank you.  That seemed to work, but I am confused as to why.  I have a number of other urls setup the exact same way, and none of them needed the CBV function imported.  Do you know why this is?  I can show you the code if needed.